# Large set of widgets in kivy - optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, kivy, kivy-language

I have a music app written with **kivymd** that scans your **default download directory** and extracts information about your audio files. (Basically **retrieving the IDV3 tags** and other things)

I only have 20 audio files at max on my desktop which shouldn't be a problem but I decided to test my program with many audio (like 120) files and the results were **horrible**.

The interface was so slow that it barely worked. How am I supposed to display large set of widgets in kivy without causing such **catastrophic performance degradation?**

Also, how can I make the loading of the widgets **asynchronous** so that they don't take up a lot of time on startup as well?

A minimal reproducible example of my code:

```
import os
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RectangularRippleBehavior
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class Song:
    """Class for extracting information about an audio file."""
    def __init__(self, path: str):
        self._path = path
        self._title = "My Song"
        self._artist = "Unknown artist"
        # the album cover is going to a texture retrieved from the file itself
        # but in this case, I will refer to a file.
        self._album_cover = "Default-Album-Cover.jpg"

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self._path

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self._title

    @property
    def artist(self):
        return self._artist

    @property
    def album_cover(self):
        return self._album_cover


class SongCard(ButtonBehavior, RectangularRippleBehavior, MDBoxLayout):
    """Custom widget for creating cards."""
    song_obj = ObjectProperty(Song("dummy song"), rebind=True)


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
<SongCard>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "300dp"
    radius: ("10dp",)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: app.theme_cls.bg_dark
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: root.radius
    FitImage:
        source: root.song_obj.album_cover
    MDLabel:
        text: root.song_obj.title
        adaptive_height: True
    MDLabel:
        text: root.song_obj.artist
        adaptive_height: True
ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: False
    MDGridLayout:
        id: song_grid
        cols: 2
        adaptive_height: True
        spacing: "10dp"
        padding: "10dp"
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv

    def on_start(self):
        for _ in range(25):
            for audio_file in os.listdir(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), "Downloads")):
                if audio_file.endswith(".mp3"):
                    song_obj = Song(audio_file)
                    self.kv.ids.song_grid.add_widget(
                        SongCard(
                            song_obj=song_obj
                        )
                    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RecycleView class to manage the amount of widgets and help your program to be able to accept a big amount of widgets, the ScrollView is great but recycleview manages data as dictionary and then you can use two BoxLayout class under a BoxLayout widget to have the GridLayout class functionality, I tested this with 213 elements and it works with a lot of widgets and good performance:

```
import os
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RectangularRippleBehavior
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout



class Song:
    """Class for extracting information about an audio file."""
    def __init__(self, path: str):
        self._path = path
        self._title = "My Song"
        self._artist = "Unknown artist"
        # the album cover is going to a texture retrieved from the file itself
        # but in this case, I will refer to a file.
        self._album_cover = "Default-Album-Cover.jpg"

##    @property
##    def path(self):
##        return self._path
##
##    @property
##    def title(self):
##        return self._title
##
##    @property
##    def artist(self):
##        return self._artist
##
##    @property
##    def album_cover(self):
##        return self._album_cover


class SongCard(MDBoxLayout):
    """Custom widget for creating cards."""
    #song_obj = ObjectProperty(Song("dummy song"), rebind=True)
    song_obj = StringProperty()

class B2(ButtonBehavior, RectangularRippleBehavior, MDBoxLayout):
    """Custom widget for creating cards."""
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
<SongCard>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "300dp"
    #radius: ("10dp",)
    BoxLayout:
        padding: dp(10)
        spacing: dp(5)
        B2:
            padding: dp(10)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: [0,1,0,.2]
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    radius: [30,]
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: dp(5)
            FitImage:
                size_hint: 1,1
                source: "Help5/cc.png" #root.song_obj.album_cover
            MDLabel:
                text: root.song_obj[:40] #.title
                adaptive_height: True
            MDLabel:
                text: " - jbsidis"  #.artist
                adaptive_height: True
                
        B2:
            padding: dp(10)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: [1,0,0,.2]
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    radius: [30,]
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: dp(5)
            FitImage:
                source: "Help5/cc.png" #root.song_obj.album_cover
            MDLabel:
                text: root.song_obj[:40] #.title
                adaptive_height: True
            MDLabel:
                text: " - jbsidis"   #.artist
                adaptive_height: True

Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        #do_scroll_x: False
        RecycleSupportGridLayoutjbsidis:
            id: song_grid
            key_viewclass: 'viewclass'
            key_size: 'height'

            RecycleBoxLayout:
                padding: dp(10)
                default_size: None, dp(248)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'


<RecycleSupportGridLayoutjbsidis@RecycleView>:

''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv

    def on_start(self):
        #for _ in range(25):
        for audio_file in os.listdir("/media/jbsidis/Android/Q/D/Anthony Robbins/"): #os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), "Downloads")
            #if audio_file.endswith(".mp3"):
            #song_obj = Song(audio_file)
            self.kv.ids.song_grid.data.append(
                {
                    "viewclass": "SongCard",
                    "song_obj": audio_file
                    }
                )


##                {
##                    "viewclass": "CustomOneLineIconListItem",
##                    "icon": name_icon,
##                    "text": name_icon,
##                    "on_release": lambda:Clipboard.copy(name_icon),
##                }


##                    self.kv.ids.song_grid.add_widget(
##                        SongCard(
##                            song_obj=song_obj
##                        )
##                    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Pictures:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but when I run your code I get a **TypeError** saying: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: Alright, do you see the line number where the type error is? It's weird since my example is not using conditional like ```if "hi" > 6```, which would throw that error type

Comment: I fixed it, there was something wrong with the default_size of the recycleview